# Strange way to load the google map

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, cordova

I am using AngularJS + ionic and I am trying to create a google map. I am using the plugin cordova to get the exact position of the user and it works. In addition, the map is loaded only when the person takes a photo, there, is where obtendo such data. So there I have no problem, but the way the map is loaded strange, is clipped and navigation is pesima. I leave you my code and a picture of how the map looks.

```
<map center="{{latitud}}, {{longitud}}" zoom="15" style="width:100%;height:100%;" data-tap-disabled="true" id="mapa_view">
  <marker position="{{latitud}}, {{longitud}}" />
</map>




.controller("CamaraCtrl", function($scope,$rootScope, Camera,$cordovaGeolocation) {

var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
$cordovaGeolocation
  .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
  .then(function (position) {
    var latitud_actual  = position.coords.latitude
    var longitud_actual = position.coords.longitude
    $scope.latitud = latitud_actual;
    $scope.longitud = longitud_actual;

  }, function(err) {
    // error
  });

  $scope.mostrar_form = false;
  $scope.getPhoto = function() {
    Camera.getPicture().then(function(imageURI) {
      console.log(imageURI);
      $scope.lastPhoto = imageURI;
      $scope.mostrar_form = true;

    }, function(err) {
      console.err(err);
    }, {
      quality: 75,
      targetWidth: 320,
      targetHeight: 320,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    });
  };
  $scope.getPhoto();
})
```

[image: img]

Comment: This happens when the map is resized.  You have to manually trigger a resize on the google map object.  In your success callback, try trigging the resize.  `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')`  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226497/how-to-update-the-google-map-if-the-map-canvas-of-it-changed-its-dimenstions for more information.

Comment: First, thanks for your help. I already try to use this method does not work. It's probably like this using either, as I am loading the map. This is how I think the map.

Comment: <map center="{{latitud}}, {{longitud}}" zoom="15" style="width:100%;height:100%;" data-tap-disabled="true" id="mapa_view">
            <marker position="{{latitud}}, {{longitud}}" />
          </map>

Comment: Hmm, I haven't poked around with that directive implementation for google maps.  Taking a quick look, I don't see any easy way to trigger the event.

Comment: I still do not solve this problem -.-